# iTunes won't play from Apple TV

Tags: itunes, appletv

I've had Apple TV for just over a week and up until today, everything has been fine. My problem is that when I try and watch previously bought films/tv shows, they won't play. It just goes back to the play screen. Also, I cannot buy new films. I've reset it, logged off and back on again but still the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you in the US, Australia, Europe?  Have you updated the firmware on the apple TV?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an amazing internet pipe, don't bother trying to play purchasef TV, etc, from the TV or Movies icon on ATV.

Download the TV, etc, to your Mac/PC, turn on iTunes Home Sharing on the Mac/PC and on the ATV, choose "Computer" on the ATV, and stream it from the Mac/PC to the ATV.

Comment: What do you mean by "amazing pipe".  I just have a standard ADSL 2Mbps down and have had never had issues. Refer to http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3623 for specific requirements to play HD content and troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm on (A)DSL 3Mbps, and the time it takes to open a streaming video from Apple (not from my Mac), is measured in hours.  The ATV loves showing TV shows we purchase in the main "Movies" and "TV" icons (well, in the "topshelf" when the icon is selected below), but selecting the video from there causes it to be streamed from Apple, playing hours later.  For me.  Is it different for others?  Download the content to your local Mac/PC/iTunes, turn on Home Sharing, and select the computer in the ATV's "Computer" menu.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with your network set up, or your ATV.  They should stream perfectly.  I was using Apple TV in Australia with a 1Mbps ADSL and streaming movies was instantaneous. I would go through the troubleshooting steps I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to: [support.apple.com/kb/TS3623](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3623) for specific requirements to play HD content and troubleshoot.

Where it states:

> For the best viewing experience when renting or purchasing iTunes
>   content on Apple TV, you need a broadband Internet connection. A
>   sustained 8 Mbit/s or faster Internet connection is recommended for
>   viewing 1080p high-definition movies and TV shows, 6 Mbit/s or faster
>   is recommended for viewing 720p content, and 2.5 Mbit/s or faster for
>   standard-definition content. Internet connection speeds may vary
>   depending on your ISP and other factors.

The apple site goes on to provide further troubleshooting tips, with the following items to be checked or implemented in order to provide better playback/streaming perfromance:

1. Check your home network;
2. Wireless connection;
3. Wired (Ethernet) connection;
4. High Definition vs. Standard Definition;
5. Update your Apple TV software; and
6. Verify DNS and network settings.

To change to standard definition follow these instructions:

> If your Internet connection is too slow to quickly start playing
>   High Definition movies or TV shows, consider changing your iTunes
>   Store Video Resolution preference to Standard Definition. To do so,
>   from the main iTunes menu, choose Settings > iTunes Store, and toggle
>   the "1080p HD" or "720p HD" option to "Standard Definition". Movie and
>   TV show purchases and rentals will now be in Standard Definition.

Answer (score 1):

I would try unlinking all devices from your iCloud and relink.

Also this ensures all devices are using the same iCloud account.